# Методы взаимодействия клиента и сервера при написании блога

Tags: javascript, post, get

я пишу блог на javascript, html, css и node js (без express). Новичок в вебе, поэтому возник вопрос - какими методами (GET или POST) клиент должен взаимодействовать с сервером при создании, редактировании и удалении постов? И почему. Причем, видимо, должны быть две роли - админ (то есть я - человек, который пишет этот блог) и пользователь (человек, который этот блог читает). Админ, наверное, может всё get-запросами делать, а для пользователей нужны post (кроме удаления - там delete), так?

Comment: Совсем не так. POST запрос служит для того, чтобы отправлять данные, а GET чтобы получать. **И это для всех одинаково, что админ, что пользователь.** Для блога скорее вам ничего кроме POST и GET не понадобится. А чтобы обновлять данные постов в БД, точно также в формочке ставите метод POST, получаете данные из него и вставляете эти данные в SQL запрос, в котором уже указываете метод UPDATE в теле запроса и подставляете полученные данные из POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Клиент (человек, который этот блог читает) и Админ(то есть я - человек, который пишет этот блог). Эти два сущности для вашего сервера является клиентом.
Допустим такой сценарий. Пусть  Юра(админ) добавляет через админ панель статью на блог. Потом эту статью читает Саша(клиент) и оставляет комментарий. Данном случае Юра и Саша клиенты сервера.

Прочитайте про HTTP и REST.

- GET — Получение данных;
- POST — Добавление новых данных;
- UPDATE —   Обновление данных;
- DELETE — Удаление данных;

То есть, если нам нужно обновить базы данные на сервере, то мы должны использовать тип запроса UPDATE.

Также в качестве данных как правило отправляется JSON массив, на определённый URL, на нём грубо говоря срабатывает функция и уже зависимо от отправленных данных и типа запроса будет происходить какое-то действие.

Также, одна из важнейших особенностей в том, что не важно с какого устройства будут отправляться данные, с браузера или с мобильного телефона, это не важно.